# how to create database in which answers decide what the next window will show

Tags: mysql

I am creating an app and i am facing problem related to creating normalized database.

It is having questions and answers.Firstly question will appear and its answer will decide the next question.Everything is fine if user selects one answer only.If user will select multiple answers of question then how will next question be showed!!

for example- answers are having checkbox and user can select multiple.How to design database for it .
Quick help is appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Table structure may look like below, user wise entry with answers selected:

**tbl_answer**

```
pk_id question_id answer_id user_id
1         1         1         2
2         1         2         2
3         1         3         2
4         2         2         3
5         2         4         3
```